# Accessing JSON feeds

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I wanted to access JSON feeds automatically.

Suppose I am given [this website](http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/products/#sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&group=7&page=1), the information in the table obtained through another link: `http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/ProductSlate/V1/List/500/1?sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=7&r=rSG3qVq3`
  (from XHR) but there are 3 other pages (shown above the table), which also contain tables like this. 
I want to access (suppose n pages) and (n tables, 1 for each page). Is there an automatic way to do so?

Right now, I have copied the links to each of the JSON feeds and stored in them in a txt file which I read from file.

Comment: This URL returns HTML, not JSON.

Comment: What do you mean automatically? This url is html not json. You're not so clear what your intention is.

Comment: So basically, I want to copy the contents in the table. As you can see, this link (copied from XHR) is http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/ProductSlate/V1/List/500/1?sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&venues=3&page=1&cleared=1&group=7&r=rSG3qVq3 has all the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the fields `500/1` and `page=1` in the url. Something like:

```
page = 2
url = 'http:/ ... st/500/{0}?sortField=oi ... page={0}&clear ...'.format(page)
```

To find out the number of pages you should scrap the original page, for example(not tested) using [pyquery](http://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/):

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
d = pq(html)
selector = '#cmeProductSlatePaginiationTop ul'
n_pages = len(d(selector))-2
```

Comment: I think I need to change /List/500/2 and page=2

Comment: You are right, checked again and this is the case

Comment: So the n_pages will have all of the pages and the next step would : for i in n_pages url = 'http:/ ... st/500/{i}?sortField=oi ... page={i}&clear ...'

Comment: No *n_pages* will be an *int* for example **3**, so: `for page in xrange(1,n_pages+1): ...`

Comment: Why do we do n_pages+1? If there are 3 pages, then shouldn't we stop at n_pages?

Comment: Also, could you re-post what you had before you edited your answer

Comment: it is the way xrange() works, in the end you will get (1,2,3)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30345/discussion-between-elyase-and-josh)

Answer (score 1):

I opened chrome's developer tools network tab. When the link to the second page is pressed this is the XHR url:

http://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/ProductSlate/V1/List/500/2?sortField=oi&sortAsc=false&group=7&page=2&r=hkVMMcCL

As you can see, you need to change `/List/500/1` as well as the `page=1` field. The developer tools are very useful for this kind of thing.

Comment: So I would need to set a boolean, checking if /List/500/2 exists or not...

Comment: I don't think so, you can treat the 500/2 page exactly the same as the 500/1 page

Comment: But I need to check total number of pages, so whats the best way around that?

Comment: I would get 500/2, 500/3... etc until I get a 404 (page not found) response

Comment: I just tried that, and it keeps giving me something (just tried 10 for example), although the fields I want to accept as inputs are given in {}, but not a 404 erorr

Comment: You can scrap the original page, see my updated answer.

Comment: I suppose, then, that you could get a page, try parsing it and stop getting pages once "the field you want to accept as input" becomes {}